# Using select() with STDIN on windows?

Tags: c, windows, sockets, select, stdin

Coming from a linux background, I'm used to the concept that everything is a file, i.e. sockets AND stdin.

This makes it easy to write a simple server/client using select(), where I include STDIN in the fdset so it'll allow me to use the terminal for input, especially for debugging.

Moving to windows however, the concept of "everything is a file" does not hold anymore.
using select() for stdin (even after defining STDIN_FILENO as 0) simply doesn't work.

What's the best way to port a code using select() (for both stdin and actual sockets) to work on windows?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23164492/how-can-i-detect-if-there-is-input-waiting-on-stdin-on-windows

Answer (score 3):

You really answered the question (in part) already.  The rules for sockets on Windows and Linux are *similar* (as far as concept) but not exactly the same.

Here is a link that discusses ***[porting Windows to Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617478/porting-winsock-to-linux-sockets)***.

And here is one ***[porting Linux to Windows](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?515211-Porting-socket-program-from-Linux-to-Windows)***. (read the links in the bottom post.)

Comment: neither of these mentions using select for stdin?

Comment: @TimBaker -   _[select](https://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/bsd-compatibility.html)_ is mentioned in both the first _and_ second link I provided.  ( via this site:  https://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/bsd-compatibility.html )  Thanks.

Comment: :o sorry about that. I missed it! thank you! it's listed under poll.

Comment: @Tim - No problem.  If you are the recent down-voter, does my comment satisfy the reason so that you can retract your down-vote?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help @ryyker, I didn't realize I had down voted that, since the links were helpful.

Comment: Hi Ryyker, I'm having EXACTLY this question but you supply two links that in turn link to many other pages that link to other pages.  I cannot find mention of using stdin's fileno with select on WIN32.  Can you  specifically answer that question?

Comment: @SwissFrank - Windows does not use fileno, it rather uses handles as a way to reference an established socket.  Did you happen to look at the link provided to a similar question in the 2nd comment?  It contains [this link](https://tangentsoft.com/wskfaq/advanced.html#64sockets) for focused discussion on sockets, include use of _select_.   Beyond that, it may be best for you to post a separate question and include the specifics of what you need there.